# Can someone explain the reason for this?

Tags: powershell

[image]

This is my code both `$test` and `$strstring` are arrays filled with strings (as you can see from the screenshot), however the program shows `Object[]` for `$test` and `String[]` for `$strlist`, but the strings are identical, so what is the cause of "false" result?

```
$list = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | ft -HideTableHeaders Name |
        Out-String
$list = $list.Split("`r")
$test = gc C:\Windows\System32\test.txt
```

where `$test` is obtained via `$list | Set-Content test.txt`.

Comment: Is the output of `'-{0}-' -f $test[1]` and `'-{0}-' -f $strlist[1]` identical? Is the output of `[char[]]$test[1] | % { [int]$_ }` and `[char[]]$strlist[1] | % { [int]$_ }` identical?

Comment: Yes and yes, however the GetHashed code is different for them (i googled a bit and found out that for same string values their hashed codes must be the same right?)

Comment: probably one of the characters is not the same is the other (just looks the same to the hoooman)?

Comment: Can you post the info about how you get your `$test` and `$strlist`? Also, can you post exact value you get from `($test[1].GetEnumerator() | % { [int]$_ }) -join '-'` and from `($strlist[1].GetEnumerator() | % { [int]$_ }) -join '-'`.

Comment: more info about those objects is welcome

Comment: $test=gc "C:\users\rubom\desktop\Test1\test.txt"
$strlist= Get-wmiobject -Class win32_product | ft -hidetableheaders Name | out-string
$strlist= $strlist.Split("`n",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

Comment: the test.txt file is obtained via $strlist | set-content test.txt so they SHOULD be the same. I obtain the list  from the commands above then save them in the test.txt file , later i obtain them by doing get-content, but when i compare them they are different

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Jqh71 also here are the results

Comment: I guess that `$test[1].Length -eq $strlist[1].Length` returns `False` (there is a  difference in terminating carriage return, value `13`).

Comment: Please post actual, functional code in your question, not a screenshot of code (or your results, for that matter). It's impossible to copy & paste your code from a screenshot.

Comment: $list= get-wmiobject -Class win32_product | ft -HideTableHeaders Name | Out-string
$list | set-content test.txt
$test= gc C:\Windows\System32\test.txt 
$list=$list.Split("`r")
$test[1] -eq $list[1]

Comment: this is all the code i executed, also sorry im new to stack overflow, if you could help me out to figure out how to do this i would be very glad, basically what is needed is to compare a list of programs in some txt file with installed software on the current pc

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is practically unreadable. Also, given that code it's clearly not possible that the snippets from my initial comment would have produced the same output for `$test[1]` and `$list[1]`.

Comment: Show how you created those objects.

Comment: @MickyBalladelli i edited the post hope now its clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you create those object is not correct, you are relying on the output of format-table, then splitting by `r which removes a character. Meaning that two strings are not the same. See length.

A way to do it is:

```
$list= (get-wmiobject -Class win32_product).name
$list | set-content d:\temp\test.txt
$test= gc d:\temp\test.txt

$list[0] -like $test[0]
```